# is there a way to specify the "UbuntuOne" folder in windows?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-xp, directory

Installed the beta Ubuntu One on XP, for some reason the "UbunuOne" folder was not created, instead my shared folder is the root of C:\ drive.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but no change.

Can you specify or change the shared UbuntuOne folder?

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Windows application does not connect automatically.
First of all you need to add your PC to your account which I assume you have already done as it is looking at the C: Drive

When you right click on the status icon by the clock you should see Status : Idle.
Click on this and it will change to syncing.
Only after this point will it create a UbuntuOne folder.

This should then allow you to play around with your files 'cross-platform'.
There are a few limitations to the public Beta however based on the recent changes to the home page and the removal of the Beta link from one.Ubuntu.com you can assume it will be released or at least made RTM very soon.

Comment: OK thanks for clearing that up, I have now synchronized and the Ubuntu One folder has been created. I was just a bit cautious about syncing when it looked like I would sync the C:\ drive.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you!